# Excel 2010: Run time error 1004 general odbc error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a small Excel 2010 query that either times out (not responding) then gets the error `Run time error 1004 general odbc error`

When I debug it highlights this line:

```
 Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

This was working in Excel 2007.

I tried `On Error Resume Next` to get the query to skip any errors and move to the next part but that didn't help.

```
Sub Refresh_all()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.Goto Reference:="querycell"
    Range("A2").Select

    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt   
    Next ws

    Application.Goto Reference:="returncell"
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line do you receive the error on?

Comment: @Gareth ill try and get it to error again, but mostly it just times out (excel not responding). is there any syntax that isn't compatible in 2010?

Comment: Is it still timing out even if you remove the `On Error Resume Next` statement? Apart from that are you sure you are wanting to refer to the `ActiveWorkbook` rather than `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: @Gareth removed On Error Resume Next and changed it to THIS and now i get the Run time error 1004 general odbc error and when i click debug it highlights this line Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange solution to this, but i'm putting it up in case anyone in the future finds them selves in this quandary!

In the Command text one of the lines was:

```
WHERE i.c LIKE NVL(?, '%')
```

Which for some reason worked in Excel 2007 but not in 2010

By changing it to this it worked as before

```
WHERE i.c = ?
```

I'm sure someone more intelligent than me will come along and give reasoning behind this, but until then, thats what solved it